# Finding all $z$ which satisfy $|\Re(z^2)| \equiv |\Re(z)|$ and $|\Im(z^2)| \equiv |\Im(z)|$

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $z=(x+yi)$

$ x \in \mathbb{Z} , y \in \mathbb{Z} $

I am searching for complex numbers which satisfy following equations:

$|\Re(z^2)| \equiv |\Re(z)| \; ( \bmod \; b^{\lfloor\log_{b}(|\Re(z)|)+1\rfloor} ) \wedge $

$ |\Im(z^2)| \equiv |\Im(z)| \; ( \bmod \; b^{\lfloor\log_{b}(|\Im(z)|)+1\rfloor} ) \; , b \in \mathbb{N} $

Which is:

$ |x^2 - y^2| \equiv |x| \; ( \bmod \; b^{\lfloor\log_{b}(|x|)+1\rfloor} ) \wedge$

$ |2xy| \equiv |y| \; ( \bmod \; b^{\lfloor\log_{b}(|y|)+1\rfloor} )$

The basic idea about these modulo equations is that $x^2−y^2$ ends with the digits of $x$ and $2xy$ ends with the digits of $y$, ignoring the signs. e.g. $−123$ ends with $23$.

$b$ is a base. I would be happy if it could be solved with $b=10$. But it would be even better if it could be solved for any base $b$.

An example of a complex number in base $b=10$:

(**313** + **216**i)² = 51**313** + 135**216**i

So far, I have found [1447 numbers using a brute-force algorithm](https://misc.daniel-marschall.de/math/immortal/complex.php), but it is stuck and I wonder if there is more to find or if the amount of numbers was finite.

The smallest found number is $(8 + 4i)$, the biggest found number is $(959106445313 + 749939593216i)$. For some reason, extremely many numbers have $\Im(z)=60406784$.

Is there a rule or algorithm to find all possible $(x,y)$ tuples? Are there infinite numbers which satisfy these equations?

Comment: ??? What is $b$?

Comment: What is the absolute value in the modulo world?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter My guess is that by $|s|\equiv |t| \mod m$ the OP could mean: $s\equiv t \mod m$ or $s \equiv -t \mod m$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to define $b$. It is a base. I would be happy if it could be solved with $b=10$. But it would be even better if it could be solved for any base $b$.  The basic idea about these modulo equations is that $2xy$ ends with the digits of $y$, and $x^2 - y^2$ ends with the digits if $x$, ignoring the signs. e.g. $-123$ ends with $23$.